# Create your own colour library in android for use with renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

I would like to create my own colour library in order to apply some pixel processing using my own colours and not the default ones.

For example when using the `rsUnpackColor8888` I would like to define my own black colour value somewhere. I know that I can define a colour like :

```
const float4 kBlack = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

but the problem is I have to go through all pixels and compare the colour with the value I got from `rsUnpackColor8888` . I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. rsUnpackColor8888 is implemented as

uchar4 in = ...;
float4 out = in * (1.f / 255.f);

It would be easy to reimplement that within a kernel if necessary. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: By doing this you don't always get the exact colour you want because of the fact that these operations are with float numbers. The reason I try to implement this is because I want to match the colour of a pixel from a custom made library rather than let the kernel give me some value.